# Why do we believe it?

Tags: tipitaka

When we attend a meeting; just right after we leave the meeting room, every one understands the conclusions of the meeting differently. Even if it is written, every one interprets the message of the written message differently.

In politic, people distort messages for their favor, even when the message is recorded, the interpretation can be quiet different.

How do we believe in the ancient Tipitaka whether it is genuine or altered. We don't know the real teaching of lord Buddha. We believe what we believe as we interpret things on our own favor. We have our own versions of Buddhism that fit ourselves. Each of us has our own version of religion.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Buddhism SE. We also have a [Resource tab](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) and a [Guide](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post) for new users that you might like.

Answer (score 3):

It should be verified through pratice by what you experience at the experiential level. If you experience something you know for a fact it is true.

Normal you should:

1. Learn the theory (Pariyatti)
2. Practice what you learned (Patipatti)
3. Experience what you learned why which you verify the teachings (Pativedha)

When you reach 3 your doubts will be cleared as you know for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Tripitaks especially those first two ones Sutra Pitaka and Vinaya Pitakas they are written after the tradition of oral trasmission of the teaching of Buddha.

Even in these days in certain asian buddihst tradition, written transmission is not conducted because an individual practicionals awareness is all different to person to person. They are guided individually.

It applies to Buddhas teaching when he was alive the Dharma was trasmitted oral only, and the 10 deciples memorized all those and were written in Pitakas from their perfecrt recollections after the first council. You can highly rely on their recollections. They are telling the truth in simple terms.

With regards to how do you know?
Once you see the glimpse of the truth
And your world changes upside down with shedding of tears you just know there is no difference in writings of Dharma. Buddha nature or Buddha seeds are same regardless of who, when, where realizes.

Tripitakas are diamond jewel where direct descriptipns of Buddha are found.

Answer (score 1):

This question cannot be "answered" because I believe it hits us humans, straight at the core of our faith and understanding of everything in general.

Buddhism is just one of the routes to enlightenment. It is not a religion. But unfortunately some people take it as such because they are skewed to "faith". It gives them a false sense of "hope". A hope that says there is a "savior" among us in our hearts. What we don't understand is that spirituality is actually subjective. How we realize the ultimate, is up to us.

I don't wish to go through a whole load of drivel just to make you understand that belief and faith works everywhere in our world. It happens with all religions, politicians, social media, advertising, add your own list here. Belief and blind faith seeps through our very roots in society.

There may be a point in questioning beliefs but ultimately that is just to ground yourself in reality and see things as they are. You cannot really, totally change what's around you. I'd suggest using common sense and questioning for yourself at best along with practice.

Comment: But Lord Buddha said directly that Nirvana is the only permanent enlightenment. Also said that others show paths that can give temporary freedom that is not the same with Nirvana. Lord Buddha confirmed Buddhism's teaching as the only path, not as another path.

Comment: According to your logic, only true "Buddhists" can be enlightened. If I look at history, this isn't true about these so called enlightened people.

Comment: Well it depends on what you call enlightenment.For example for Hindu people a birth among Brahmas is enlightenment, and there they have some comfort because of the extremely long life. But Lord Buddha said that it is not an enlightenment as the birth there is impermanent just like being human. And they have not escaped from Samsara. Once the question was asked from Lord Buddha......

Comment: ......The answer was... "I have looked Back an extremely long time into the past, i saw no one who reached Nirvana without the presence of the path. Only one has ever reached a heavenly realm without the help of the path, even he believed in Karma."  To say that there is enlightenment beyond the path is giving a personal view. What others call enlightenment is not up to me to define. What i meant was Nirvana, our enlightenment can't be achieved by any other path. Namo Buddhaya!

Comment: I just proved how we can go on and on with stories and so called quotes of what somebody may have said by ascribing to faith. I can quote a few deathless saints here but that's all I'll be doing really, quoting those deathless saints and I'll never truly know. Unless I become deathless myself.

Comment: Also, what is that thing about Hindus you said? I need sources or experience. I need not buy whatever you say just because you seem to be so "faithful" and comparative, my friend. And just so you know, I am born in a Brahmin family. I am obviously not enlightened. Did you just pull that out of your you-know-what...or faith?

Comment: I did not mean a Brahmin family, I meant the incidents like the one Lord Buddha encountered when Lord Buddha saw  a Brahama thinking that he is the beginning. This Brahma thought that he is the creator because he did not saw anyone else being born there. Lord Buddha personally visited him to explain his misunderstanding. The brahma thought he is immortal and in realization of all because he lived very long and no one was born there.   Also in another incident, Other teachers who lived in Lord Buddha's time taught....

Comment: ..... how to reach the Brahma realm through meditation. They considered this as the prime achievement and the salvation. I have heard that this practice still exits in India. What i meant by Brahmas was that, not the human caste called Brahmin. Learn the Suttra Pitaka of Tipitaka and you will see what's right. Hope i did not got you angry. Lord Buddha said something that i repeated on my answer, i do not give my opinions here and if i do i mention it first. Namo Buddhaya!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how and why it all happened if that helps you....

After Lord Buddha the teaching was kept alive by the monks who learned and kept it by heart, they did it in few different ways. Some individuals kept it all while some learned chapters.

Time to time they would come together for a reciting. This would be called a [**Council**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_councils), It is essentially a global gathering of monks who have the teaching by  heart. Here they would each recite the teaching that they have kept. This was done to clear any doubts and clean the error as all the other are listening and chanting too.

---

In Sri Lanka the same tradition went on until an all island drought came. Some monks went to india and some stayed in the island. They hardly saved themselves but a lot of Arahats passed away because of the drought. They decided that the Oral tradition is not reassuring as they saw it first hand. So they did another Gathering or a "Council" and this time they wrote teaching. This Became the "Tipitaka" of Theravada.

So the whole process was done right and transparently.

---

This is how it happened. I should remind you that if one chooses to put away the tipitaka he or she ends up with nothing else but his or her own version of things that his or her mind construct to benefit. Without the tipitaka there is no Buddhism left to follow.

I must say that one thing you said is wrong. It is not a Buddhist thing to make our own version. I agree that we all interpret the teaching in our own way, but one should not make personal beliefs. But the teaching is open to different interpretations as we all are with different wisdom and intelligence.

Namo Buddhaya!